# Check if a number is in string delimited by seperator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `varchar` field like this `1-2-55-9`

How can make a query to check if a number is in this field ?

```
select * from x where TEST
```

What test to do if For example `55 -> yes return record` , `5 -> no` , `7-> no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use **a `like` statement**. The syntax is standard SQL and therefor also applicable on other dbms like Oracle or SQL Server.

```
select * from x where (test like '%-55-%') or (test like '55-%') or (test like '%-55')
```

The like patterns use wildcards (i.e. `%`). The example above uses 3 conditions (in order of appearance):

- contains `-55-`
- or starts with `55-`
- or ends with `-55`

Alternatively **you could use a regex to combine all 3 conditions**:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE test regexp '(^|-)55($|-)'
```

Here it says that the string `55` should be preceded either by a `-` or it should be at the beginning. And it should be followed by a `-` or should be at the end.

Here is a short explanation of the regex syntax:

- `(a|b)` matches `a` or `b`
- `^` means the start of a value
- `$` is the end of a value

*PS: You could also use `rlike` instead of `regexp`, they are identical.*

See also [the mysql documentation for pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: thanks it seems to be a good solution to be implemented on hibernate but can we combine the 3 `or` with just one regular expression no ?

Comment: lol, I'm adding that. give me a minute :) there is indeed an `rlike` keyword in mysql.

Comment: thanks @bvdb i accept your answer because it can be used in `hibernate` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`INSTR`**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php) Function

```
select case when INSTR ('1-2-5-9', '5') > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' End
```

**Update :**

Use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php) Function.

```
SELECT case when FIND_IN_SET('55',replace('1-2-55-9','-',','))>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' END
```

Comment: @Youssef - Updated try now

Comment: thanks it works but it will be great if we can directly specify `-` as seperator

Answer (score 0):

If string contains the required number return yes else return no.

```
 select if(LOCATE('5','1-2-5-9')>0,'yes','no')
```

Tested and works!

Comment: no it return `yes` in this case `select if(LOCATE('5','1-2-55-9')>0,'yes','no');` which is wrong